# array syntax: private classType[] identifier = new classType[] {};

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I'm reading Android Programming:
The Big Nerd Ranch Guide and i dont understand the following java syntax. can someone explain this java syntax or at least dierct me where to find explanation;

```
private classType[] identifier = new classType[] {
                                // several lines of new classType(arg0, agr1) };
```

here is an example on page 39:

```
private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[]{
new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
};
```

I'm used to arrays with syntax like this: `private classType[] identifier = new classType[]`. The part I don't get is the curly braces. Thanks for answering

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of declaration an `array` in `Java`.

1. you can use `int[] arr=new int[4];`  // giving the size
2. You can use `int[] arr =new int[]{1,2,3,4}` // giving element too

Both ways are valid declaration. 1st case you need to tell the size of the `array` but not the elements. In 2nd case you don't need to tell the size of the `array`, You need to provide elements of `array`.

In addition to these two you can use

```
int[] arr={1,2,3,4};
```

too

Comment: Note that `new int[]` in the second variant is optional.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to declare/instantiate an array :

- Declare by length. Elements are initialized by the default value of their type.

  ```
  int [] array = new int[7] ;
  ```
- Declare and initialize.

  ```
  int [] array = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
  ```
- Instantiate a new initialized array. This syntax can be used at declaration but is it pointless since the previous syntax is shorter and does the same. Use this if your array is already declared.

  ```
  array = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
  ```

Comment: What does your answer have to do with the question?